# Missing headers when sending mail from python

Tags: python, email

I'm having a weird problem with sending out e-mail from a python script.

This one works perfectly:

```
msg = MIMEText(body)
msg['Subject'] = 'Booking confirmation %s, %s.'% (tourname, tourdatetime.strftime('%d %b %Y, %H:%M'))
msg['From'] = FROMADDRESS
msg['To'] = email
msg['Cc'] = OWNERADDRESS
s = smtplib.SMTP(MAILSERVER)
s.sendmail(FROMADDRESS, [email, OWNERADDRESS], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

The received e-mail looks exactly as I expect it to.

From the same server, the following snippet doesn't work properly: the e-mail is sent out to the correct recipients, the attachment is there, but the To: and the Cc: headers are missing from the mail that's been received. The subject, body and From: are set correctly.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = FROMADDRESS
msg['To'] = data['email']
msg['Cc'] = OWNERADDRESS
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(
    file(
        os.path.join(
            directory, '../images', 'meetingpoint_%s.jpg'% (data['tourid'], ))
        ).read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % ('meetingpoint_%s.jpg'% (data['tourid'], ), ))
msg.attach(part)
smtp.sendmail(FROMADDRESS, [data['email'], OWNERADDRESS], msg.as_string())
```

Comment: what do the contents of `data['email']` and `email` look like? Why are you not using `MIMEImage` ?

Comment: Both 'email' and data['email'] are a single e-mail address as string. And I'm doing it this way with as it's based on the example given in the Python docs, and example code from an answer to a related question elsewhere on this web site, regarding adding image attachments to e-mails.

Comment: The [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) I saw uses MIMEImage and supports multiple files: `msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)`